# Output the call stack when the program crashes along with the symbol names

Tags: c++

I want to output the call stack when I catch an unhandled exception and my program crashes. I want to do this while the program is still alive, without any post-mortem analysis.

I would rather not use any third-party libraries, which is what most of the answers to similar questions suggest. I'm trying to use StackWalk here.

I am trying to get this to work on Windows.

Here's what I have:

```
DWORD machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;

HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
HANDLE thread = GetCurrentThread();
CONTEXT context = {};
context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
RtlCaptureContext(&context);

SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE);
SymSetOptions(SYMOPT_LOAD_LINES);

STACKFRAME frame = {};
frame.AddrPC.Offset = context.Eip;
frame.AddrPC.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
frame.AddrFrame.Offset = context.Ebp;
frame.AddrFrame.Mode = AddrModeFlat;
frame.AddrStack.Offset = context.Esp;
frame.AddrStack.Mode = AddrModeFlat;

while (StackWalk(machine, process, thread, &frame, &context, NULL, SymFunctionTableAccess, SymGetModuleBase, NULL))
{
    char * functionName;
    char symbolBuffer[sizeof(IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL) + 255];
    PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL symbol = (PIMAGEHLP_SYMBOL)symbolBuffer;
    symbol->SizeOfStruct = (sizeof IMAGEHLP_SYMBOL) + 255;
    symbol->MaxNameLength = 254;

    if (SymGetSymFromAddr(process, frame.AddrPC.Offset, NULL, symbol))
    {
        functionName = symbol->Name;
        std::string str(functionName);

        std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());
        LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();

        MessageBox(NULL, sw, L"Error", MB_ICONERROR | MB_OK); //for testing purposes
        if (str.find("nvd3dum") != std::string::npos) {
            //I'd put a messagebox here telling the user to do something if I find a symbol name I recognize
       }
  }
}
```

The problem I have with it is that instead of outputting the call stack of when the program crashed, I get this very function that was called, along with stuff like RtlCaptureContext that I used in this very function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. I've seen a lot of people have the same problem as me. Put it into correct context!

```
CONTEXT context = {};
context.ContextFlags = exceptionInfo->ContextRecord->ContextFlags;
context.Eip = exceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Eip;
context.Ebp = exceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Ebp;
context.Esp = exceptionInfo->ContextRecord->Esp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is not required to exist in C++. Read carefully the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), the call stack is not mentioned there. So that in theory, some C++ compilers could be clever enough to avoid any call stack (for some particular program given to that compiler). Many C++ compilers are optimizing [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) (so share the same memory locations between calling and called functions and their call frame).

In practice, C++ implementations follow the [As-if rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule). They can, and often do, [optimize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) to the point of [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) functions, even those you did not annotate with `inline`. When that happens, speaking of call frame for an inlined function makes no sense.

Also notice that *some* [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) are practically not on the call stack. A compiler is permitted to (and generally does) put some variables only in [processor registers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register), without spilling them into the call stack. Read about [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation). A given slot in your call frame could be used to keep several unrelated variables.

So, showing the call stack is a quality-of-implementation issue and could depend of *external* factors (such as the optimization levels you required when compiling your C++ code). On Linux, I recommend using Ian Taylor [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace). I guess you could find a similar library for call stack inspection on Windows.